# Custom Archetype

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-archetype

I made a custom archetype from on an existing project (in eclipse) with the basic structure for a web service.

```
mvn archetype:create-from-project
```

Then I installed the archetype locally:

```
\target\generated-sources\archetype\mvn install archetype:update-local-catalog
```

But, when I try to use my archetype in Eclipse (Maven Project->Select local archetype) I have a problem with a .project file.

```
"Failed to read the project description file (.project) for 'testname-proj'. 
The file has been changed on disk, and it now contains invalid information.  The project will not function properly until the description file is restored to a valid state."
```

However, the project exist in my disk, but doesn't show it within eclipse IDE.

I had followed the same steps in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_nTvBA787g

UPDATE:

I solved it deleting .project, .classpath and .setting files.

Comment: Have you saved your `.project` file into the archetype accidentally?

Comment: I followed the explanation of the video without remove any files, but finally I solved it deleting _.project_, _.classpath_ and _.setting_ files.

Comment: Yes, they shouldn't be included in the archetype.